# talked to him in a bad mood

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity

> a. Have you ever talked to John in a bad mood?
>
> b. Have you ever talked to him in a bad mood?

Can we tell who is in a bad mood, you or John/him?

Comment: Yeah, whoever is frowning.

Comment: It's ambiguous, you have to rephrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of ambiguity is common in English humor.  There's an old joke from the famous comedian Groucho Marx:

> [One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfN_gcjGoJo)

The first line is meant to give you the impression that the speaker was wearing pajamas when he shot the elephant, and it's funny when Marx twists the sentence to the unlikely (but still syntactically valid) alternate meaning.

So, yes, in your example, it's not clear who is in the bad mood.  If you want it to be clear, you would have to restructure the sentence.